# trouble merging; i'm using vscode and coworker is using sublime, vscode is saving formatting in the file, making diffs hard to read

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, code-formatting

Basically what I asked in the title. I clone a repo down, make some changes, push it up and when we review the diffs, it includes all of the formatting differences between the original file and what I pushed up. So if I change one line, I'm getting hundreds or thousands of differences. When we ignore whitespace, it's better, but for obvious reasons, new lines are not ignored. This is on a fresh install of vscode, no plugins (other than bracket pair colorizing). Anybody have any idea of why vscode is saving the formatting changes, or how I can turn that off?

Comment: What OS are you on? Might be some LF->CLRF shenanigans

Comment: if LF problem you can configure git to always commit and checkout using a particular ending. VSC out of the box does no formatting, or I have disabled them all. Look/search in Settings for `format`

Comment: we're both on the same OS

Comment: It would be useful if you could let us know what the formatting differences are, perhaps with some screenshots of the diff. I've provided an answer that might be able to help you deal with line-ending troubles and auto-formatting on VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few different possibilities for why your VSCode is auto-formatting, I've provided some possible ones in the picture below.

1. First, go to the settings located at the bottom left
2. Next, search for eol (end of line)
3. Make sure that Eol has been set to 'auto', so that VSCode does not auto-format line endings
4. You can turn off Formatting on certain files by clicking the 'Formatting' area in the bottom bar.

[image]

---

Also, if you wish to keep the same line endings throughout your git repo, you can create a .gitattributes file under your git directory, and add in the preferred eol settings there, like so:

[image]

---

Finally, if you notice that VSCode is formatting your code as you save it, you can turn that off by going to the settings.json file that is under your project folder directory, and making sure that the line `"editor.formatOnSave": true` is commented out with `\\`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: if VS Code has the option to trim trailing white space on save (Sublime does, for example) that can also be a source of pain if one person has it turned off and another has it turned on.

Comment: That's a good point. If I could make a recommendation, it would be to use the same formatter, eg. clang-format, as the same formatter for both editors.

Comment: Formatting checks done on the pipeline can also prevent merge conflicts due to whitespace.